# how to make those white button boxes?

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to somehow make those boxes and use buttons in it but I am unable to do so please help me doing it.

I tried using opacity but it clear button input and was not what I was excepting!

[image]

Comment: Show us your HTML + CSS so we can help

Comment: The boxes look like they are input or textarea  HTML elements. Have you tried using them and please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a CSS framework you can use to easily code forms and other layout

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

there are other wireframes too such as Bulma but I find Bootstrap the easiest to work with

Comment: I think you did not understand my question I post the image too. I want to make same form like the image but I am unable to make the white boxes .

Answer (score 0):

I feel those white boxes have a transparent background color and a transparent border color. So, the CSS for those boxes will go something along these lines:

```
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
border:2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, do you want buttons within the white input boxes? It isn't possible to have a button within an input.

To create those white input boxes, you need to use `<input type="text">` for small text inputs and to create the larger inputs like *Address* you want to use CSS to size the input box bigger.

Of course to style those input boxes white and with curved edges you'll need to add a `class="your-css-class"` tag-helper within the *input* tag. Said CSS class will need to have `color:white;` and `border-radius:5%;` for example to add the styling.

To create that default text in the input boxes you can use the tag-helper `value="Enter your adress here..."` in your `<input>` tag.

To get each input label and input box within those green boxes you should use *flexbox*. This is an easy framework, read more here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Those green boxes can each be a `<div>` tag with the label and input tags within it, and all the green boxes together should be encompassed in a `<div>` tag. The individual `<div>` tags for each green box can share a class that styles them using flexbox properties like `flex-direction:row;` to get the label and input next to each other horizontally. Lastly, the `<div>` tag encompassing all of those smaller ones can be styled with the flexbox property `flex-direction:column;` to get the green boxes to show vertically.

To add flexbox add the CSS property `display:flex;` to your overall `<div>` tag encompassing all green boxes/`<div>`s and also the individual `<div>` tags representing the individual green boxes.

Hope this helps.